# c# how pass parameters to process OutputHandler?

Tags: c#, process

I am open some `process` and read its output and I want to pass this function another param:

```
    public void Start(string fileName, string arguments)
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
        process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputHandler);
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    }

    private void OutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
        {
            string line = e.Data;
            if (line != null)
                {

                }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You want another method to be able to read the string line (or send line).  right now you have line inside a private method so it is not accessible.  You need to make line more accessible.

Comment: how to do that ? and why i cannot send another param from my Start method to OutputHandler ?

Comment: Just move string line = ""; outside the OutputHandler method.

Comment: No option to pass some object to OutputHandler metthod instead of declare it as global ?